# Error al crear programa con clase para saber smartphone marca codelearn y smartphone con más memoria

Tags: c#

resulta que este programa me da error en la línea 25. Mi intención era diseñar un programa que pida al usuario un número n. A continuación el programa debe leer la información de n teléfonos móviles. Concretamente, por cada teléfono móvil, hay que leer: la marca, el modelo, la memoria y el sistema operativo. Finalmente, el programa debe mostrar cuántos de estos teléfono son de la marca "Codelearn" así como cuál es el teléfono con más memoria.

Para lograr esto, debo crear una clase Smartphone y definir sus propiedades y accesos, así como su constructor parametrizado. Además, almaceno los datos de los teléfonos en un array de teléfonos móviles.

Un buen funcionamiento del programa sería el siguiente:

```
Insert total number of smartphones: 3
Insert brand of smartphones: Codelearn
Insert model of smartphones: Python
Insert memory of smartphones: 3
Insert os of smartphones: Android
Insert brand of smartphones: Codelearn
Insert model of smartphones: Karel
Insert memory of smartphones: 2
Insert os of smartphones: Android
Insert brand of smartphones: Codelearn
Insert model of smartphones: Logo
Insert memory of smartphones: 1
Insert os of smartphones: Android
There are 3 Codelearn Smartphones
The smartphone with more memory is Python Codelearn
Press any key.
```

Adjunto el código:

```
    using System;
    
    namespace moviles
    {
class Smartphone
    {
        private string brand;
        private string model;
        private string so;
        private int memory;
        public string Brand
        {
            get { return brand; }
            set { value = brand; }
        }
        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { value = model; }
        }
        public string So
        {
            get { return so; }
            set { value = so; }
        }
        public int Memory
        {
            get { return memory; }
            set { value = memory; }
        }
        public Smartphone(string brand, string model, string so, int memory) 
        {
            this.brand = brand;
            this.model = model;
            this.so = so;
            this.memory = memory;
        }
    }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int vegades, memory;
                string so, model, brand;
                Console.WriteLine("Insert total number of smartphones: ");
                vegades = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Smartphone[] sp = new Smartphone[vegades];
                for (int i = 1; i <= vegades; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert brand of smartphones: ");
                    brand = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert model of smartphones: ");
                    model = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert memory of smartphones: ");
                    memory = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert  os of smartphones: ");
                    so = Console.ReadLine();
                    sp[i] = new Smartphone(brand, model, so, memory);
                }
                if(vegades < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no smartphone");
                }
                else
                {
                    Smartphone mx = sp[0];
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= vegades; i++)
                    {
                        if(sp[i].Brand == "Codelearn")
                        {
                            counter += 1;
                        }
                        if (sp[i].Memory == mx.Memory)
                        {
                            mx = sp[i];
                        }
    
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("There are [0] Codelearn", counter);
                    Console.WriteLine("The smartphone with more memory is {0} {1}", mx.Model, mx.Brand);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: te falta decir que error te da y cual es la linea 25

Answer (score 0):

Revise el código, y lo que pude detectar es que inicializas tu array con `n` que es la variable `vegades`, y tus dos ciclos los inicias en 1, cuando los arrays son base 0, por lo que tendrías que iniciar en 0 para acceder a el ítem `0 .. n-1` de tu array, ese es el motivo que te genera error, ya que intentas acceder a un item que no existe.

El otro error que vi es solo uno muy simple, al imprimir la cantidad lo pones con `[0]` y debería ir `{0}`.

```
using System;

namespace moviles
{
    class Smartphone
    {
        private string brand;
        private string model;
        private string so;
        private int memory;
        public string Brand
        {
            get { return brand; }
            set { value = brand; }
        }
        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { value = model; }
        }
        public string So
        {
            get { return so; }
            set { value = so; }
        }
        public int Memory
        {
            get { return memory; }
            set { value = memory; }
        }
        public Smartphone(string brand, string model, string so, int memory)
        {
            this.brand = brand;
            this.model = model;
            this.so = so;
            this.memory = memory;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int vegades, memory;
            string so, model, brand;
            Console.WriteLine("Insert total number of smartphones: ");
            vegades = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Smartphone[] sp = new Smartphone[vegades];
            for (int i = 0; i < vegades; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert brand of smartphones: ");
                brand = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert model of smartphones: ");
                model = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert memory of smartphones: ");
                memory = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert  os of smartphones: ");
                so = Console.ReadLine();
                sp[i] = new Smartphone(brand, model, so, memory);
            }
            if (vegades < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no smartphone");
            }
            else
            {
                Smartphone mx = sp[0];
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < vegades; i++)
                {
                    if (sp[i].Brand == "Codelearn")
                    {
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                    if (sp[i].Memory == mx.Memory)
                    {
                        mx = sp[i];
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Codelearn", counter);
                Console.WriteLine("The smartphone with more memory is {0} {1}", mx.Model, mx.Brand);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```